# Estimation of $I_n=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{1+x+\ldots+x^n} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

Let $I_n=\int_1^\infty \frac{1}{1+x+\ldots+x^n} dx$. I'm being asked to determine in 3 different ways whether $\sum_{n\geq 2} I_n$ converges.

I've noticed that $I_n$ rewrites alternatively as $$\int_1^\infty \frac{x-1}{x^{n+1}-1} dx =\int_0^1 \frac{1-x}{1-x^{n+1}} x^{n-2} dx.$$

I've also noticed that $0\leq I_n\leq \int_1^{\infty} \frac 1{x^n} dx = \frac 1{n-1}$, hence the estimate $I_n = O(\frac 1n)$. I'm not sure whether this estimate is tight, or whether it can be refined.

I tried to refine the upper bound as $I_n\leq \int_1^{\infty} \frac 1{x^{n-1} + x^n} dx$, but this looks like a deadend.

Comment: Using your result
$$I_n=\int_0^1\frac{x^{n-2}-x^{n-1}}{1-x^{n+1}}dx\overset{t=x^{n+1}}{=}\frac1{n+1}\int_0^1\frac{t^{-\frac2{n+1}}-t^{-\frac1{n+1}}}{1-t}dt$$
denoting $\epsilon=\frac1{n+1}$
$$I_n=\epsilon\big(\psi(1-\epsilon)-\psi(1-2\epsilon)\big)=\epsilon^2\psi^{(1)}(1)+O(\epsilon^3)=\frac{\pi^2}6\frac1{(n+1)^2}+O\Big(\frac1{n^3}\Big)$$

Comment: @Svyatoslav Is $\psi$ the digamma function ? It seems that the integral représentation you're using is missing a $\log$.

Comment: Yes, $\psi$ is digamma and $\psi^{(1)}$ is trigamma functions. I used the representation $$\psi(1+z)=-\gamma+\int_0^1\frac{1-t^z}{1-t}dt$$ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $k = \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$. For $n \ge 3$ and $x \ge 1$ is
$$
 1 + x + \cdots + x^n \ge x^{k+1} + \cdots + x^{2k} \ge k x^{k+1}
$$
and therefore
$$
 I_n \le \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{kx^{k+1}} dx = \frac{1}{k^2} \le   \frac{1}{(n/2-1)^2}= \frac{4}{(n-2)^2} \, .
$$
It follows that $\sum I_n$ is convergent.

Comment: Note that $I_n\geq \frac 1{n+1} \int_1^\infty \frac 1{x^n} dx = \frac 1{n^2-1}$, hence your estimate has the correct order.

Comment: As a follow-up, is there a constant $C$ such that $I_n\sim \frac C{n^2}$ ?

Comment: @Marloumarlou: My guess woud be “yes” but I do not have a proof right now.